# How to properly rig the shoulder of this low poly model?

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting

How to properly rig the shoulder of this low poly model?
Have tweaked weights, but didn't get desired results. Is there any other problem?

Edit: Link to File: https://pasteall.org/blend/b5a93745a9f44db79dc5ed6a48179b92

- By desired results, I meant that the area below the arms is also getting distorted, which I didnt want. Is there any problem in the mesh itself?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: What are the desired results?

Comment: You should name the bones from the model's point of view, *not* from your point of view. That is, swap left and right. hand.L <=> hand.R, LowerArm.L, and so on. *hand.L* is the left hand of the model. Then you can use the menu Armature > Symmetrize command properly.

Comment: Yes I did the naming manually and maybe that might also be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to :

- Go in *Edit* mode, some normals are flipped, recalculate them
- Add some edge loops so that your armature is able to bend the object:

[image]

- Reparent *With Automatic Weight*
- Bring some corrections in *Weight Paint* mode

Answer (score 0):

This model is little bit low poly for rigging. Try to subdivide it more, if that doesn't work then it has issue with the bone weights. Try separating the arms(as a different mesh) and then rig it with the same skeleton.
See if that works.

Comment: Did try to subdivide, but couldnt do it. I will also try the second option